# Can a Pentium G4400 Stock Heatsink/Fan work for an i7 7700T?

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling

I have a Pentium G4400 which has been acting in my NAS for about the period of a year quite faithfully. It's a little limited in it's ability and this was expected as I've always anticipated replacing it. Recently I have stumbled onto the i7-7700T which has a decent power consumption while having performance not very far from an actual 7700.

Some quick facts about the G4400 and 7700T I feel are pertinent:

- The [G4400](https://ark.intel.com/products/88179/Intel-Pentium-Processor-G4400-3M-Cache-3-30-GHz-) has a TDP of 54 watts
- The [i7-7700T](https://ark.intel.com/products/97122/Intel-Core-i7-7700T-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3-80-GHz-) has a TDP of 35 watts

Given that the Pentium G4400 has a TDP of 54w and the 7700T has a TDP of 35W is it safe to say then that the G4400 stock heatsink is sufficient for the 7700t?

Attaching a reference heatsink image for illustration:
[image: stock g4400 heatsink]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will be sufficient as the TDP of 7700T is less than that of  Pentium G4400. It will keep the system cool.